# Does "Disable and Delete" delete photos from your Apple devices after 30 days? or will they only be deleted in iCloud.com?

Tags: icloud

Does "Disable and Delete" delete photos from your Apple devices after 30 days?. I mean, if iCloud Photos remains turned on in iPhone, for example after the 30 days, will the photos be deleted?

Comment: What context are you talking about?  What are you trying to do that you see this message?

Comment: I turned on "disable and delete" in iPhone settings, so that all photos will be removed in iCloud after 30 days.  My doubt is if the photos will also be deleted in iPhone after those 30 days if leave iCloud Photos turned on in iPhone.  I guess they won't, but I'd like to know.  Just for knowledge sake, I'm a technician.  Thank you.

Comment: So you want to permanently delete those photos?  Turning on "disable and delete" will give you 30 days to download your photos from iCloud before they're permanently deleted.

Comment: All I want to know is if the pictures will be deleted on the devices in which iCloud photos is turned on after those 30 days.

Comment: I *think* that if you turn iCloud Photos back on after that 30, the pictures on your iPhone will be re-synced back to iCloud.  I don't have any info that they would be deleted from your iPhone.

Comment: icloud photos is already activated.  You’re probably right that photos wont delete in iphone.  I'd like to know for certain.  Thank you

Comment: You might wan to consider adding a bounty to this question to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt that they won't be deleted.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250261013